# Sum possibilities, one loop

Tags: python

Earlier I had a lot of wonderful programmers help me get a function done. however the instructor wanted it in a single loop and all the working solutions used multiple loops.

I wrote an another program that almost solves the problem. Instead of using a loop to compare all the values, you have to use the function has_key to see if that specific key exists. Answer of that will rid you of the need to iter through the dictionary to find matching values because u can just know if they are matching or not.
again, charCount is just a function that enters the constants of itself into a dictionary and returns the dictionary.

```
def sumPair(theList, n):
    for a, b in level5.charCount(theList).iteritems():    
        x = n - a     
        if level5.charCount(theList).get(a):
            if a == x:
                if b > 1: #this checks that the frequency of the number is greater then one so the program wouldn't try to multiply a single possibility by itself and use it (example is 6+6=12. there could be a single 6 but it will return 6+6
                    return a, x
            else:
                if level5.charCount(theList).get(a) != x:
                    return a, x           
print sumPair([6,3,8,3,2,8,3,2], 9)
```

I need to just make this code find the sum without iteration by seeing if the current element exists in the list of elements.

Comment: Don't use `has_key`, it's deprecated. Just use `if a inlevel5.charCount(theList):`. However, I don't see why that's necessary at all, since you know `a` is a key in `level5.charCount(theList)` because you just got it from there.

Comment: the guy says i can't use 'in'

Comment: @Web Master:  how about `__contains__` ?  ;-)

Comment: @WebMaster: Do what he says since it's for a class, just know that it's not the best way in the real world. `has_key` doesn't even exist in more recent versions of python.

Comment: look, i have absolutely no idea how to do this. i've spent more then 15 hours on this single problem. i don't have to use the has key or the get. but i must not use any iterations after the first "    for a, b in level5.charCount(theList).iteritems():  "

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some context, but I can't tell what the question is. What the heck is `inlevel5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) function instead of the `level5.charCount`

And I don't know why you need to check `if level5.charCount(theList).get(a):`. I think it is no need. `a` is the key you get from the `level5.charCount(theList)`

So I simplify you code:

```
form collections import Counter

def sumPair(the_list, n):
    for a, b in Counter(the_list).iteritems():
        x = n - a
        if a == x and b >1:
            return a, x
        if a != x and b != x:
            return a, x

print sumPair([6, 3, 8, 3, 2, 8, 3, 2], 9)   #output>>> (8, 1)
```

The also can use [List Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) like this:

```
>>>result = [(a, n-a) for a, b in Counter(the_list).iteritems() if a==n-a and b>1 or (a != n-a and b != n-a)]
>>>print result
[(8, 1), (2, 7), (3, 6), (6, 3)]
>>>print result[0]   #this is the result you want
(8, 1)
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. the output is supposed to be one of the two numbers in the sum pair. so 9 is supposed to be 3 and 6

Comment: @WebMaster I don't know what do you want. Can you give some other example?